# Is there a way to validate an email address using the fuelsdk?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

Title states it all, Is there a way to validate an email address using the fuel sdk? (php in particular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PHP FuelSDK - there is a method layer available to you - in this instance you would use the ET_PostRest constructor which looks like this:

```
class ET_PostRest extends ET_Constructor {
    function __construct($authStub, $url, $props) {
        $restResponse = restPost($url, json_encode($props));            
        parent::__construct($restResponse->body, $restResponse->httpcode, true);                            
    }
}
```

Your SDK call would look like this:

```
$myClient = new ET_Client();
$authStub = $myClient;
$url = "https://www.exacttargetapis.com/address/v1/validateEmail"
$props = array("email" => "help@example.com", "validators" => array("SyntaxValidator", "MXValidator", "ListDetectiveValidator"));

$return = $ET_PostRest($authStub, $url, $props);
```

Give that a whirl.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the $ET_PostRest, I think this should be more clearly shown in the documentation because the SDK documentation never mentions that API functions are available, only shows SOAP functions and examples.

Comment: In my opinion all the PostRest functions should work just like the SOAP ones, and the SDK should know whether to make a SOAP call or PostRest call, isn't that the point of this SDK?

Comment: They do when the objects are per defined, but the SDK's are not 100%. If you use one of the predefined objects, it behaves like this. And yes - the documentation is something we are working on addressing.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, see the link below:

https://code.exacttarget.com/api/address-validateemail

I don't see that specific example in the PHP samples but the page walks you through building the call.