# PHP Fuel SDK PostRest Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

Based on the answer provided [in this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29017/is-there-a-way-to-validate-an-email-address-using-the-fuelsdk) - my actual code follows -,

```
$myClient = new ET_Client(true, true);
$authStub = $myClient;
$url = "https://www.exacttargetapis.com/address/v1/validateEmail";
$props = array("email" => $EmailAddress, "validators" => array("SyntaxValidator", "MXValidator", "ListDetectiveValidator"));

$return = new ET_PostRest($authStub, $url, $props);

var_export($return);
exit();
```

I am getting the following response

```
ET_PostRest::__set_state(array(
   'status' => false,
   'code' => 401,
   'message' => NULL,
   'results' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'documentation' => 'https://code.docs.exacttarget.com/rest/errors/403',
     'errorcode' => 0,
     'message' => 'Not Authorized',
  )),
   'request_id' => NULL,
   'moreResults' => NULL,
))
```

SOAP based calls are working fine, so I must be missing something with the REST Auth.

Answer (score 1):

ET_PostRest is after the point in the process where the access_token is applied to the request so it would need to be applied manually.

Where is current says:
$url = "https://www.exacttargetapis.com/address/v1/validateEmail";

Replace it with:
$url = "https://www.exacttargetapis.com/address/v1/validateEmail?access_token=".$authStub->getAuthToken();

Comment: I guess that means the SDK doesn't handle REST token management then yet?

I thought since i was setting up a new ET_Client and passing $authStub it would be taken care of. I didn't see it applied in the class anywhere but I also don't know what the ?legacy=1 that does get added does.

Comment: oops, wasn't reading your post correctly and didn't realize the authToken was coming from $authStub

Comment: if i make the request too often (less than 5 minutes) then i get
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided.: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided, requestToken response:{"additionalErrors":null,"documentation":"http:\/\/jssvc-s1.xt.local:80\/AuthService\/v1\/requestToken?legacy=1","errorcode":1,"field":null,"fieldErrors":null,"message":"Unauthorized","objectErrors":null,"path":null,"validationErrors":null}' in /ET_Client.php on line 107`

Comment: i realize this is still under development and i built my own class before i knew this existed, but I'd still like to understand the SDK for REST as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

Why not just improving the Class ET_PostRest?
(that does actually ignore the param authStub... why?)

```
<?php
class ET_PostRest extends ET_Constructor {
    function __construct(ET_Client $authStub, $url, $props) {

        $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

        $url .= !empty($query)?'&':'?';
        $url .= 'access_token='.$authStub->getAuthToken();

        $restResponse = restPost($url, json_encode($props));            
        parent::__construct($restResponse->body, $restResponse->httpcode, true);                            
    }
}
```

....
Usage:

```
<?php     
 $myclient = new ET_Client();
 $props = array("email" => $email, "validators" => array("SyntaxValidator", "MXValidator", "ListDetectiveValidator"));

 $return = new ET_PostRest($myclient, $url, $props);

 var_dump($return);
```